# this Eror happen in Generated signed apk

Tags: flutter

I was creating APK for my flutter project so I followed the below steps to generate a signed APK

Tools -> Flutter -> Open for editing in android studio

Then opened the model in a new window

I got the Gradle sync failed error, After my further investigation I run the command gradlew --warning-mode all in the terminal & I got the below message from gradle

The AbstractArchiveTask.destinationDir property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the destinationDirectory property instead.

I also tried org.grdle.wranning=(all,summary,fail,none)

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate a signed APK you don't necessarily have to open your Android project as you described in your issue.
The steps you have to follow are :
1- Create your keystore.
2- Plug this keystore with the `android/app/build.gradle` file
3- Enable the signing in your release buildType in the `android/app/build.gradle` file

```
buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

This is just an overview of the steps you have to follow.
The full procedure with examples in available on the official [docs.flutter.dev website](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#signing-the-app)

Don't worry too much about the warning. It only means that you some of the methods used in your `build.gradle` will be deprecated soon.